# Writing a prefix function Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell [I am loving Haskell by the way :)].
The problem is that I want to write a function myPrefix that takes as input a list, and gives as output the list consisting of all prefixes of the input-list. For Example:

```
*Main> prefix [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

But I can not think of a way to do it.
If some one can please give me a push in the right direction, I will be in debt.

I have tried to find related posts but I could not find any, SO I posted a question.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: A little tip: If you know the signature of the function you want, then you can search for it on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D). In both cases, the first result for `[a] -> [[a]]` is actually the answer you are looking for. Of course, it's not always that easy, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: @PeterHall, thank you Peter, very useful tip!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library function `inits` does what you want.

Otherwise, consider this:

```
prefix :: [a] -> [[a]]
prefix [] = baseCase
prefix (x:xs) = doSomethingTo (prefix xs)
```

Can you guess what `baseCase` and `doSomethingTo` should be?

For the latter: think about how to transform

```
prefix [2,3] = [[], [2], [2,3]]
```

into

```
prefix [1,2,3] = [[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

A way to do that is to first transform `[[], [2], [2,3]]` into `[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]` and then add the additional `[]` in front of that.

Comment: This turns out to be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
suffixes, prefices :: [a] -> [[a]]

suffixes []          = [] : []
suffixes lst@(_ : s) = lst : suffixes s

prefices []  = [] : []
prefices lst = lst : prefices (init lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Poin-free solution:

```
prefixes = foldr (\el acc -> [] : map (el:) acc) [[]]
```